# Can you set field properties in Custom List View declaratively?

Tags: list-view, xml

**Background,** I created a custom list view. FriendlyDisplayFormat on "Modified" is set to Unspecified so the result is that we get as seen in the first image:

[image]

But if we change the value of the to *Disabled* we get the result I want:

[image]

**Question:** Can I change the value of FriendlyDisplayFormat the from my custom view or is there a better way to do this?

I just want to change the value for this view. 
SharePoint 2013.

Comment: This option is on the list column. Isnt it?

Comment: Yes, that right.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Sorry but isnt the two pictures showing this (should i explain more in the question, if so what?). But I want the possibility to not see the text in the Modified field, Just the date or date&time.

Comment: Set FriendlyDisplayFormat to disabled.. Doesnt that display date time? Is that that you want to do this for only 1 view?

Comment: I can change the value of the property by using SharePoint Manager, PowerShell, Manually but since i just want it of a view that is on new Sites. But ye it solves the task but it would be nice to have it done automatically for just this view when i create a new sub site with a custom template with the library that have my custom view.